# How to Generate the multiple unique keys for test data?

Tags: apex

I am inserting the test data for a object, it has a unique field . I need to have 200 unique string for test data. I have tried below code , but it gives duplicate values some time.

```
Set<String> duplicateValues = new Set<string>();
Integer duplicateCounter = 0;
for(integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){ 
    Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
    String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
    String isocode = key.substring(0,3);
    if(!duplicateValues.contains(isocode)){
        duplicateValues.add(isocode);
    } else {
        duplicateCounter ++;
        system.debug('Containing the Duplicate values' + isocode);
    }
}
System.debug('Number of Duplicates in Salesforce' + duplicateCounter);
```

What is the best to generate the 200 unique 3 char keys . Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176060/1737819

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need so many test records? If you're simply trying to test that your code is "bulkified", there are other methods to test this (instead of creating a lot of records).

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of performance, I would simply decrement the counter on duplicates. Here's how that might look:

```
for(integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){ 
  String isocode = 
    EncodingUtil.convertToHex(
      crypto.generateAesKey(128)
    ).left(3);
  if(!duplicateValues.add(isocode)){
    i--; // duplicate found
  }
}
```

This uses the fact that Set.add returns false when a duplicate is detected, and true otherwise.

Comment: Sorry but didn't get this . I need 200 unique values . I have used the duplicates values to identity the duplicate. however, I need to set of 200 unique values of 3 char to enter the test data.

Comment: @SFDC_CloudBee Set.add returns false when there's already a duplicate, so this code will return 200 unique values.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the easiest way to accomplish that is change loop type from for to while

if SET's size not equals to 200, continue.

```
while(duplicateValues.size() < 200) {
            .......
}
```

Comment: Sorry but didn't get this . I need 200 unique values . I have used the duplicates values to identity the duplicate. I need to set of 200 unique values of 3 char to enter the test data.

Comment: Let me explain. At first, you need 200 unique values, so the exit loop condition is you had 200 values in SET. Then, you generate 3 char random value as usual, discard the value if dulipcated, it doesn't matter. No duplicate?  Put in SET. Duplicated? Discard. At the end, you'll get a duplicate value SET with 200 members.

Comment: ok . You mean , keep generating the values in while loop until I find the 200 unique values in the set.

Comment: Exactly, finally you'll get 200 unique values in the set.

Answer (score -2):

Salesforce is aware of this and they provided a feature as a workaround.

create this method

```
private static Database.DMLOptions enableDuplicate(){
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    // enable duplicate
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
    return dml;
}
```

And insert via the following command

`Database.insert(newAccs, enableDuplicate());`

Comment: While this would get around duplicate rules that may be in place, this would not help if a particular field is configured as "unique" (i.e. the "unique" checkbox is checked). From the language used in the question, I believe that this is a "unique" field rather than being an issue with duplicate rules.